# JPA single table inheritance mapping with additional join condition

Tags: hibernate, jpa, single-table-inheritance

[image]

As you can see from the above 'image' table definition there can be images owned by CATEGORY,DIVISION and few other entities. And, the JPA mapping are as follows:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "image")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "owning_entity", discriminatorType = STRING)
public class Image extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "img_key")
    protected UUID key;
  
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DIVISION")
public class DivisionImage extends Image {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owning_entity_id")
    private Division division;

...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "division")
public class Division extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "division", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<DivisionImage> images = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

My issue is that when loading the entity Division whose primary key is 3, the relationship division.images is also loading CATEGORY's images. Note that there 2 rows in the 'image' table where owning_entity_id is 3.

Is there a way to specify additional filter on the JoinColumn in Division, like so:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owning_entity_id")
    @Where(clause="owning_entity='DIVISION'")  // <-- Apparently this does not work
    private Division division;
```

so that the right images are picked?

Answer (score 0):

The @Where should be on the other side of the relationship :facepalm:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "division", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Where(clause="owning_entity='DIVISION'")
    private List<DivisionImage> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `WhereJoinTable` like below:

```
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "owning_entity ='DIVISION'")
```

Comment: On which side of the relationship?

Comment: It applies to the association table